# howto copy all text in a gnome-terminal in RHEL linux 5.3

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal, rhel-5

I work on the gnome-terminal in RHEL 5.3. Since the terminal does not have features like searching for text, etc, I usually want to copy the entire text in the terminal and paste into an editor.

In windows, with 5 key strokes, I can invoke the system menu and select `SELECT ALL` and then I can copy the selected text into clipboard.

What is an easy way to copy all the text to the clipboard in the `gnome-terminal`?

Thank you,

Comment: Other than clicking "Select All" in the menu?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : I don't get the "Select all" menu option. Pls. remember that this is RHEL 5.3 (which was released in Jan 2009)

Comment: Why don't you use redirection to save the text you are interested in into a file?

Comment: @terdon : say I'm tailing the output of a program. In a ad hoc way, I might want to search for something. I might not know beforehand that I should have redirected the output to a file. When I know, I do that but there are lots of times I don't. In windows, I don't need to know in advance, the terminal makes life easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options.

1. Go to the top of the text (mouse or Shift Home) and select all the text with the mouse, then copy it.
2. When you open the terminal type `script xxx`, all the contents will be stored in a file xxx which you can search.

Comment: I have been using your option #1 -- it's way too cumbersome. I wanted something easier.   your option #2 -- it seems better than option #1 -- the thing is I have several terminals(5-10) at any point of time and to remember which file to search is kinda going to be a pain. thanks all the same.

Comment: Option number 2 is what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A not so easy way (because it involves you to learn to work with new software) is to use
[GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html).

Inside screen use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter copy/scrollback mode. Once there you do have search capabilities with / and? for vi like search and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for emacs like search.

Once you put the cursor in the place you want to start copying hit space and move the cursor, hit space again and it will copy the block. Open any editor and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to paste.

Comment: will try and get back with feedback